# What is a proper way to create awaitable function

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have dilemma on how to actually create proper awaitable function. I don't get the entire concept fully, probably due the language barrier :)

**A**

```
public async Task<int> InsertASync(string tableName, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        int r = 0;

        using (SQLiteConnection con = NewConnection())
        {
            await con.OpenAsync();
            using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(Query_Insert(tableName, data), con))
            {
                r = await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        return r;
    }
```

or

**B**

```
public Task<int> InsertASync(string tableName, Dictionary<string, string> data)
    {
        return Task<int>.Run(async () =>
            {
                int r = 0;

                using (SQLiteConnection con = NewConnection())
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();
                    using (SQLiteCommand com = new SQLiteCommand(Query_Insert(tableName, data), con))
                    {
                        r = await com.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }

                return r;
            });
    }
```

Reason i'm wondering about it is because the way i create awaitable methods via cheap way.

*Example*

```
public void DoHeavyWork() //this will block UI
{
    //Do work
}

public Task DoHeavyWorkASync() //this won't
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
         DoHeavyWork();
    });
}
```

Comment: In option A - Your method defined that it returns Task<int>, but in return statement it returns just int, I guess that's an error?

Answer (score 1):

You want to go the `A` route. The compiler will take care of creating the returned task and returning the actual integer, when available.

You can read [Asynchronous Programming - Pause and Play with ...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456403.aspx) for some good in-depth information on what the compiler does internally (how your method is converted into a state machine)